# Задержка после паузы

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-android

Проблема такая. Есть пауза, которая стопит всю игру через Time.timeScale, ну и анимация воспроизводится. Всё работает нормально. Только игрок после снятия паузы не успевает среагировать и, чаще всего, умирает. В связи с этим стоит вопрос. Как сделать так, чтобы после того, как возобновляешь игру игроку давалось определённое кол-во времени (например пять секунд), которое выводилось(!) на экран. По типу, отжал паузу, на экране обратный отсчёт (5, 4, 3, 2, 1) и возобновилась игра. Долго гуглил, не смог ничего толкового на этот счёт найти. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 0):

ну   запрограммируй  тамйер,  например  с  помощью   сопрограм   или  хз   чего,  по  окончанию  таймера   должно   сгенерироваться  событие -     делегат ,  а    в  этот  делегат   помести   функцию  для  продолжения  игры

```
delegate void StandartEvent();
StandartEvent dgResume;
GameManager m_gameManager;

void Initialize()
{
    dgResume += m_gameManager.Resume;
}

IEnumerator ResumeTimer()
{
    int time = 5;
    while(time != 0)
    {
        Debug.Log(time);
        time--;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
    }
    if(dgResume != null) dgResume();
}
```

Comment: Почему сразу не писать `yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);`?

Comment: ну   типо  надо  ж  чтобы  каждую  секунду    выводило   на  экран